# Position controls in dynamic canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

In my application I am using a canvas which is dynamically generated at runtime. I am placing a textblock on the canvas but it is showing at top left corner of the canvas. How can I change its position. I have search and everyone is showing `myCanvas.SetLeft(myTextBlock,10);` but I could not find this command in the dropdown list.

Is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(myTextBlock);
```

`Canvas.SetLeft(myTextBlock,10);`

This will add your textblock to the children collection of myCanvas and then the `Canvas` class can allow myCanvas to control the left properties of all its children.

This is an example of an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).